# Return table from Snowflake Javascript UDF for the following SQL UDF. What should be the code modification?

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions

Following is the sql udf which need to be converted to javascript udf with same tabular output.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "TEST_UDF"()
    RETURNS TABLE ("TOTAL_CUSTOMERS" NUMBER(38,0), "COUNTRIES" NUMBER(38,0), "US_STATES" NUMBER(38,0), "CITIES" NUMBER(38,0), "MIN_AGE" VARCHAR(16777216), "MAX_AGE" VARCHAR(16777216), "WOMEN" NUMBER(38,0), "MEN" NUMBER(38,0), "OTHER" NUMBER(38,0))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS $$
        select 
        COUNT(DISTINCT(HUX_ID)) AS TOTAL_CUSTOMERS,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(COUNTRY)) AS COUNTRIES,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(STATE)) AS US_STATES,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(CITY)) AS CITIES,
        MIN(AGE) AS MIN_AGE,
        MAX(AGE) AS MAX_AGE,
        ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'F' THEN 1 END)* 100 / COUNT(GENDER),8) AS WOMEN,
        ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'M' THEN 1 END)* 100 / COUNT(GENDER),8) AS MEN,
        ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'U' THEN 1 END)* 100 / COUNT(GENDER),8) AS OTHER
        from DETAIL_CUSTOMER
        
                 order by total_CUSTOMERS desc
                 
        $$;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to return a table from javascript UDF, is that possible?